# how to select with character inserted between defined places in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

```
Id | news_photoId_head
-----------------------------
 1 | apple.jpg
 2 | banana.png
 3 | getmesones.hel.apn.jpg
------------------------------
```

**apple_T.jpg**
 **banana_T.png** 
  **getmesones.hel.apn_T.jpg** 
I want to get this format for thumbnail and size 
I have long query to do this..Please show me a simple way

```
select 
concat(substring(news_photoId_head,1,char_length(news_photoId_head)-4),
concat('_T',substring(news_photoId_head,-4))) as thumb from news;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing is unpleasantly hard in MySQL.

You might try this:

```
LEFT(colname, CHAR_LENGTH(colname)-4)
```

gets you the filename without the `.jpg` or `.png`.

```
RIGHT(colname, 4)
```

gets you the  `.jpg` or `.png`.

So,

```
  CONCAT(LEFT(colname, CHAR_LENGTH(colname)-4), '_T' ,RIGHT(colname, 4))
```

produces the result you want. The added value here over your expression is the use of `RIGHT()` and the use of three parameters, rather than two, to `CONCAT()`.

Of course, this will all break if some nitwit puts in a file called `confusion.jpeg` to your table two years from now.

Answer (score 0):

to get image format Like `jpg`, try bellow query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(news_photoId_head, -4),'.',-1) FROM users WHERE 1
```

Comment: it only give me the result of file extension .thank you

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(news_photoId_head, -4),'.',-1) FROM `users` WHERE 1   (Try this query)